# Redirect front page with 301 using Prettyfaces

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I use jsf 2.2 & prettyfaces-jsf 2-3.3.3 and have `/pages/index.xhtml` page.

I try redirect from front page to another like this:

```
<rewrite match="/" url="http://somesite.net" redirect="301" />
```

Of course, all the pages are redirected. What is the right way redirect only front page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `match` attribute is a regular expression. So you should try something like this instead:

```
<rewrite match="^/$" url="http://somesite.net" redirect="301" />
```